# How to export only wordpress website users, orders, ratings, comments and statistics?

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce, migration, elementor

I've been developing my freelancer website through the years, using the folllowing:
**Bluehost server \ Wordpress \ Hello Theme \ Elementor Pro \ Woo commerce \ Jetpack \ Litespeed Cache \ Wp Mail Stmp**

I had enough of Bluehost server and I'm planning to **migrate to Cloudways server (vultr high frequency)** Nothing special here since there are plugins to migrate and the team of Cloudways also includes the migration service.

Through the years I had **my playing around with plugins** and all kind of adventures at the cpanels and database, **leaving all this leftovers, junk and scars from this experiences**. No matter how many plugins I use to clean database, bad uninstalled plugins and widgets detectors... there is always this garbage appearing, most of unknown origin. **I want to deep clean the house but not the destroy it.**

I don't mind to recreate pages, products and posts and the design. **I want to export the history data in woocommerce from orders, users, ratings and comments. Also don't want to restart my google raking and the statistics** (that I guess will be in jetpack and in Google Analytics).

I guess more people had this day dreaming of a fresh start without putting the house down. So any ideas or experience of the best way to achieve this? Just putting my hands dirt or will I need to sacrifice some body parts?

So far, found this **Tools > Export** then opening the XML to check. Some bring junk attached.
https://woocommerce.com/document/migrating-products-between-sites/
Searching the web I only found tutorials using plugins, but from what I've tryed our they bring the junk with them.

Better suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!